# What are the difference between .Select, .Any, and .Count when using LINQ

Tags: linq

What are the difference between .Select, .Any, and .Count when using LINQ
Do you get a performance hit when using .Count just like in SQL select count(*)?
Does .Any perform faster ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean with any particular LINQ Provider? By asking performance differences between a pure `select count(*)` I believe you're targeting some kind of provider for data access in some kind of DBMS (EntityFramework, Linq2Sql, etc). You should be more speciffic, and also give a look at your providers documentation if possible.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to target a specific provider, I was just making a comparison

Comment: This question is very broad, they are not equivalent at all. Voting to close.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Count` needs to iterate the entire collection, because it (obviously) needs to count the number of instances.

`Any` finds the first occurrence & returns true or false. If there aren't any, then it needs to iterate the whole collection to try to find, but if the first instance matches then it only needs to check the first instance.

`Select` is completely different. It is used to project a collection into another collection. It does not perform any checking or filtering.

edit: In SQL terms, `Any` is like `Exists`, while `Count` is like `Count(*)`.

If I want to know whether there are any people on the street today, it is completely unnecessarily to count all the people and see if the number is >= 1. As soon as I find one person then I'm done.

Comment: That's not entirely true. It all depends on the LINQ Provider (which is omitted). The LINQ to Objects provider would try a safe cast of the `IEnumerable<T>` into a `ICollection<T>` before iterating. If succeeds, it then returns the Count property of the Collection. Also, any decent Data Access provider would interpret the Count query expression and transform it into it's corresponding `select count(*)`

Answer (score 2):

Well just based off of what the operators do:

`Select` puts items into an `IQueryable<T>` and itself technically doesn't do anything until you access the collection; however, speed will depend on the collection being queried.

`Count` enumerates the entire collection getting the amount of items in the collection, so for large collections this will be 'slow'.

`Any` returns true or false if the collection contains any items and requires only one check of the first item to return true.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use **invoices** as a list or collections of items. So you will see the differences much better.

`invoices.Count()` Returns an int with the total of items (invoices) are in the list.

`invoices.Any()` Returns a bool. **True:** if there is at least one item (invoice) in the list and **False:** if no one item (invoice) in the list.

`invoices.Select(x => x.Number)` Return only a list of "Number" with no more elements.

With the exmples above you can see the differences among: Count, Any and Select.

If you would like to know more about these functionality you can read the following references:

1. `Count()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0
2. `Any()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0
3. `Select()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0